# Removint layers and stage.draw removes click listener

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am trying to test KineticJs and learn it, so I start from basic. I have to say I didn't like the JDocs too much. Any way, I want to hide and show a layer on a stage when the stage is clicked. So I wrote the following

```
window.onload = function (){
    stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        width:800,
        height:600,
        container:'container'
    });
    console.log(backgroundLayer);
    console.log("successfully created stage")
    stage.add(backgroundLayer);
    console.log("Added layer to stage");
    stage.on('click', function(){
        console.log("In click function")

        if (backgroundLayer.visible){
            console.log("backgroundLayer is visible, Make it go away Mommy!")
            backgroundLayer.hide();
            stage.draw();
            console.log(stage);

        }else{
            console.log("Daddy I want a backgroundLayer, NOW!!")
            backgroundLayer.show();
            stage.draw();
        }

    });
}
```

but the click function only works once. After the layer dissapears I cannot click any more on stage. Does it have to do that the layer is the only Layer added on screen? How does it work exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing of KineticJS, but I do know about JS. Where does the variable backgroundLayer come from? Anyway, try the code beneath instead, and replace the alpha parameter by the correct paramater to change opacity. I suppose you can't have a click event on an object that is hidden, maybe it will work with an object that is still there but with an opacity of 0...

```
window.onload = function (){
    stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        width:800,
        height:600,
        container:'container'
    });
    stage.add(backgroundLayer);
    stage.on('click', function(){
        backgroundLayer.alpha = backgroundLayer.alpha <= 0 ? 1 : 0;
        stage.draw();
    });};
```

Comment: Thats setting it too transparent right not hidding it? backgroundLayer is initialized outside the onload function and is global.

Comment: It won't work. It changes the alpha as it should. I should mention that backgroundLayer has an Kinetic.Image added inside.